# Recover edit points in exported iPhone slow motion video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, iphone, export

You can export unmodified slow motion video files from the Photos app or using Image Capture, and the resulting file will display the slow motion start and end edit points in Quicktime. However, I have yet to find a way to share an unmodified slow motion video file from an iPhone directly. The closest I've been able to do is set the entire video as slow motion and AirDrop it.

The resulting video is 240 fps video set to 30 fps, with slowed down 44100 Hz audio. I would like to modify this video to be as close to an unmodified file as possible in order to get the Quicktime player edit points back, doing as little reencoding as possible.

I've tried this: `ffmpeg -r 240 -i IN.MOV -vf "setpts=PTS" -af "asetrate=44100*8" out.mov` which seems to work, but the transitions in and out of slow motion stutter, unlike with the unmodified file where they are smooth. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't the entire stream in slow-motion? If so, which transitions do you mean?

Comment: @Mulvya No, you can define a region where it slows down from regular playback speed to slow-motion.

Comment: @slhck, the OP says, *The closest I've been able to do is set the entire video as slow motion and AirDrop it.*. This is the video they are working with, AIUI.

Comment: @Mulvya Yeah, I just realized that I didn't (don't) understand the question. When the entire stream is set as slow motion and the ffmpeg command is run, I don't see where there could be any transitions. A visualization or some examples would help.

Comment: To be more explicit: when you AirDrop from the iPhone (or use any other method to send it, e.g., DropBox, download from iCloud, email...), it bakes in the slow motion effect into a flat 30 fps file, with the effect transitioning where you set the slow motion region. In order to retain all the frames, I set the slow motion region to the entire file, and exported that. When you edit the original in Quicktime, you also see the region markers there. When you edit the baked, exported file, you do not. I want to convert this baked file back into one that is region-editable by quicktime.

Comment: Converting the 30 fps video back to 240 fps normal speed file using the above commandline, the region markers are enabled, but the playback transitions in the QuickTime Player are jerky and stutter, unlike in the original file. I am wondering if anyone has investigated what goes into an unbaked iPhone slomo video file.

The motivation for this: I want to send/receive slomo videos directly between iPhones and be able to retain the ability to edit transitions, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You say when you edit the “baked” file, you get no region markers (which I expected), but then you say that when you run the ffmpeg command, this enables region markers again? Weird – where'd they come from if they were stripped out of the file before? But I have to admit I haven't tried messing with slo-mo files yet. (CCing @Mulvya since notifications require an @-ping)

Comment: Apparently, the region markers appear when the nominal FPS of a file goes over a certain limit. So the trick is to turn the slomo 30 fps video into a normal speed 240 fps video, with the audio sped up to match. That almost does what I want, but as I indicated, the transitions then become very jerky.